# I am getting return values from property. Is it possible?

Tags: swift

```
class TestClass {
    var testString: String = {
        print("about to initialize the property")
        return "TestString"
    }()
}

let testClass = TestClass()
print("before first call")
print(testClass.testString)
print(testClass.testString)
```

In the above program, I am getting the return value from a property. Is it possible because I have heard we been doing it for methods.

```
func method() -> String {
    return "a string"
}
```

This is what I know. Can anyone elaborate my doubt?

Comment: yes, it's possible. you can even do calculations or data processing or call to other methods before returning. You can do something like this `var fullName: String { return firstName + lastName }`. You only save `firstName` and `lastName` then get fullName like that

Comment: thanks for your help!!is there any docs that brief me  more about this ??@RJE

Comment: that is the getter. I don't have exact docu link, but you can check this out https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html (Computed Properties section)

Comment: I'm curious why you are asking if this is possible when you posted code clearly showing that it can be done.

Comment: @rmaddy i think he meant more like "How does this work?".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and recommended since Swift 3. If you need to get just one value without passing other values to compute it, this is the recommended approach.

For example, in Swift 2 you had `UIColor.redColor()` returning a red color, but since Swift 3 you need to use `UIColor.redColor`

Answer (score 0):

Yet it is possible. These are called *Computed Properties*, and are thoroughly explained in the [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)